# DB2 LUW - JSON_Table reading json array data into tabular format

Tags: db2-luw

I am trying to convert JSON array data into tabular format using [Json_Table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070414.html?pos=2). I tried to run the below query but I am getting the following errors:

> SQL‬‎/‪JSON‬‎ ‪scalar‬‎ ‪required‬‎.‪‬‎.‪‬‎ ‪SQLCODE‬‎=‪‬‎-‪16413‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪SQLSTATE‬‎=‪2203F‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪DRIVER‬‎=‪4‬‎.‪19‬‎.‪56).

The same query is working fine when the number of elements in Employees array is 1, but not otherwise.

```
SELECT E."id", E."name"
FROM JSON_TABLE
(
  '{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Kathi"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Pavan"
    }
  ]
}', 'strict $' COLUMNS
  ( 
    "id" INTEGER PATH 'strict $.Employees[*].id'
  , "name"  VARCHAR(20) PATH 'strict $.Employees[*].name'
  
  ) ERROR ON ERROR
) AS E;
```

Comment: Hi! I've formatted your question a bit to try and make it clearer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the benefit of others who are looking for some examples, i found below link in internet, example 3 basically helps with my case. We need to use JSON_Table from SysTools schema.

https://www.worldofdb2.com/profiles/blogs/convert-json-data-to-relational-format

Comment: You provided a link to DB2 for Z/OS `SYSTOOLS.JSON_TABLE` function. Be aware, that there are 2 different `JSON_TABLE` table functions in Db2 for LUW. [SYSIBM.JSON_TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070414.html) and [SYSTOOLS.JSON_TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/r0070289.html).

Comment: yeah, that is the reason why i specified schema explicitly in my answer. Though the link is for DB2 for Z/OS the logic (using Json_table along with Json_Val fuctions) still holds good for DB2 LUW for in my case. The only change being we don't need exclamation mark for table alias in DB2 LUW (TABLE(SYSTOOLS.JSON_TABLE(DATA, 'PO.items.item', 's:200')) X!)

Answer (score 0):

`JSON_TABLE` produces 1 row only per 1 json document.
You may use the following only:

```
    "id" INTEGER PATH 'strict $.Employees[n].id'
  , "name"  VARCHAR(20) PATH 'strict $.Employees[n].name'
```

where n={0, 1} for an array of 2 elements as in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your response, in my case the number of array elements are going to be dynamic, just trying to see if there is a generic way of handling this..Kindly share if there is any reference to examples of handling arrays using Json Table..I am not finding better examples on web..

Answer (score 0):

See Columns in Columns

```
Select E.id, E.name                            
  From JSON_Table(                             
         '{"Employees": [                      
            {"id":1, "name":"Me"},             
            {"id":2, "name":"Myself"},         
            {"id":3, "name":"I"}               
          ]}', '$'                             
         Columns(                              
           Nested '$.Employees[*]'             
             Columns (                         
               id   INTEGER     Path '$.id',   
               name VARCHAR(20) Path '$.name'  
             )                                 
         )                                     
       ) AS E
```